# How to create dynamic process substitution based on the input (multiple FIFOs)?

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, process-substitution, fifo

I'm trying to create multiple process substitutions based on the output from the other command, however I'm not sure how I can achieve that.

As sample scenario, I've given list of files:

```
touch a.txt b.txt c.txt d.doc e.doc f.pdf g.pdf h.xls i.xls
```

I'm making the [list of available file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352380/55075):

```
ls -1 *.* | awk -F. '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}' | sort | uniq
```

Then based on my dynamic list, I'd like to create the following FIFOs like:

```
pr -mt <(ls -1 *.doc) <(ls -1 *.pdf) <(ls -1 *.txt) <(ls -1 *.xls)
```

Which would allow me to print each set in different columns. However the above list of FIFOs is hardcoded so my goal is to find some way where I can substitute dynamic number of commands (like wildcard, using `eval` or `xargs` somehow).

Another scenario is described in [here](https://superuser.com/a/906371/87805).

I'm not interested in specific solution (workaround) to above problem, as this is only one scenario. I'm interested how I can dynamically create process substitution in shell or what additional tools I can use to achieve that.

See also: [How to create anonymous FIFO?](https://superuser.com/q/184307/87805)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to dynamically build the string and eval it:

```
eval "$(echo -n 'pr -mt '; while read ext; do echo "<(ls -1 *.$ext)"; done < list  |tr '\n' ' ' )"
```

where `list` would be the file (possibly a fifo) representing the list of extensions you want to build the command from.

`<()` essentially creates unnamed FIFOs. An eval-less alternative might be to use named ones:

```
while read ext; do mkfifo ${ext}.pipe; ls -1 *.$ext > ${ext}.pipe & done
pr -mt *.pipe
rm *.pipe  #remove the named pipes when done
```

The above assumes you don't have other file names ending with ".pipe" in your directory.